# In PHP,How to decrement quantity by 1 each time an item is ordered?

Tags: php

```
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT Quantityy FROM `corro`.`food` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $id");
$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

    $output = $r['Quantityy'];

        //encode the returned data in JSON format
        echo $output;
        $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantityy = Quantityy - 1` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $output");
}

?>
```

Comment: there is an error in coding that i cannot figure out

Comment: [What's the error message?](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/)

Comment: the full app is when i order an item using an android app on my phone
the quantity of that item in database should reduce by 1

Comment: You are using this code in productive environment where people can buy and there goes money... and using deprecated functions and messy code, bet you have also SQL injection vulnarable there :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT Quantityy,id FROM `corro`.`food` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $id");
```

and in the loop:

```
$query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantityy = Quantityy - 1 where  `food`.`id` LIKE ".$r["id"]);
```

And please check the spelling...

Comment: thanx a lot it woks briliantly

Answer (score 0):

There is a ` char in the second query which you must not put in.

```
yy = Quantityy - 1` where
                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL seems to be all over the place and there are syntax errors caused by random backticks. Instead of running a loop, try using one singular SQL statement:

```
UPDATE `corro`.`food` 
SET `food`.`Quantityy` = (`food`.`Quantityy`- 1) 
WHERE `food`.`id` = $id AND `food`.`Quantityy` >= 0
```

Also, why are you using `LIKE` when you could use `=`?

Inside the loop, you're also referencing the `food`.`id` column by quantity?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $q=FALSE;  
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

$output = $r['Quantityy'];
if($q===FALSE){
$q =  $output-1;
}else{
    $q--;
}
    //encode the returned data in JSON format
    echo $output;
    $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantityy ={$q}` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $output");
}
```